# Automated testing for GIS apps

Tags: imagery, image, scenario-testing

There are several commercial and opensource tools for regression automation. While many of them could be employed to test GIS apps, they fall short, at times, dealing with the unique characteristics and use-cases of GIS apps and their imagery.

What are some tools for validating GIS apps?

I came across one such tool called [Eggplant](http://www.testplant.com/products/eggplant/for-cross-platform-testing/). Check out their video link in the bottom. They claim to not only compare data sets but also compare images. Seems interesting!

Are there other such commercial or opensource tools we can evaluate?

Thanks,
Ramesh

Comment: You need to add more detail as to what doesn't work in the tools you have tried. And try to make it sound less like an advert

Comment: In tools like Selenium or QTP, you can compare data only. Eggplant purports you compare images also. I have apps that I need to test when I add a layer to a map, does it show the way its intended, for that bounding box and that base map? And does it maintain compatibility across various browsers and mobile devices, do the reprojections match - that sort of stuff. I only know of doing that through manually today by looking at images and comparing them against a baseline output. If there is a way to do this through a script, that reduces time to test. And I am in no way associated with Eggplant.