# Seeking testing software (like QTP, Selenium) for ArcGIS platform (Desktop and Web)?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.1, arcgis-server, software-recommendations

Does anybody know any testing software/tools for ArcGIS platform (version 10.1)?

Specifically: Customized ArcGIS Desktop application & Web application.

I researched on Google but am not able to find any specific software.  Few experts told me to try manual testing so I'm a little bit confused.

Comment: What kind of testing? Try to use industry-standard terms such as you might find in [this article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_testing).

Comment: Related: [Automated testing for GIS apps](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/35016/automated-testing-for-gis-apps)

Comment: Does your question relate to any Esri products other than ArcGIS for Desktop and ArcGIS for Server?

Comment: @All... We have created few custom application in ArcGIS Desktop environment and Few in java script environment so as per the standard procedure  I need to test and applications and then going to upload it on server..

Comment: @blah238 yes its industry based testing..I am going to upload the application at client side before that I need to perform standardized testing and here no one is familiar to GIS Testing..thanks for your suggestions

Comment: I don't know why your question was voted down. It is a valid question, about an important topic, that very few people think about.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This [presentation](http://proceedings.esri.com/library/userconf/devsummit11/papers/tech/dev-to-dev_qa_and_testing.pdf) has a list of tools on page 14, though it doesn't go into how they are used and for what purpose:

- Test Design

  - AETG
  - PICT
- Automation tools

  - Python
  - SilkTest
  - JUnit
  - XTest
  - C#
  - Selenium
  - Visual Studio Team Test

For ArcObjects unit testing, see [this question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/1393/how-to-unit-test-arcobjects-with-mocking), as well as [this article](http://www.esri.com/news/arcuser/0110/noyles.html) for some suggestions.

Regarding ArcGIS Server performance/load testing, this [presentation](http://proceedings.esri.com/library/userconf/devsummit10/papers/tech/2010_arcgis_server_performance_and_scalability-testing_methodologies.pdf) suggests an additional set of tools, and offers up some pros/cons for each:

- LoadRunner
- Silk Performer
- Visual Studio Team Test
- JMeter

Answer (score 2):

I think that the question is not complete at all. I mean, testing **what** with **what** purpose? When you want to benchmark the performance of a tool, you have to specify a concrete task to do. This output is usually compared with the performance for the same task but with another tool, i. e. ArcGIS Desktop vs QGIS or gvSIG.

A particular use case for testing could be running a terrain model for a particular region, reprojecting all points of a huge shapefile or doing some 3D rendering with flythroughs. Usually you count the time that it takes to do each task and then decide which tool is better.

So the thing is, choosing a task to do and see the performance, if not, you have to go to a general testing. Considering you do not want to do a general sw testing, **what do you expect** from ArcGIS for Desktop?

Comment: I don't think there is any indication that @Sunil is talking about Benchmark Testing against other products but +1 for taking a stab at a question that needs more detail

Comment: @iamgin yes its industry based testing..I am going to upload the application at client side before that I need to perform standardized testing and here no one is familiar to GIS Testing..thanks for your suggestions

Answer (score 0):

Selenium is a great open source framework to do [test automation](https://laxmiassociates.in/services/gis-testing/) but it suffers from problems due to flaky tests, not being updated on a regular basis (since it is open source) and the need for technical resources to write automation code.

Below are good alternatives to Selenium and are currently popular-

[Appvance](https://appvance.com/)
[Test.ai](https://test.ai/)
[SikuliX](http://sikulix.com/)
[Unified Functional Testing (UFT)](https://www.functionize.com/)
[TestStudio](https://www.telerik.com/teststudio)